How to convert an ANSI-encoded CSV file to UTF-8-encoded using DataWeave in Mule 4
I am fetching a CSV file that is encoded in ANSI and contains special characters. However, when I read the file and attempt to transform it, the special characters are being replaced. Interestingly, if I manually convert the same file to UTF-8 using Notepad++, I am able to process the file properly with the special characters intact.
How to convert the encoding of the file from ANSI to UTF-8 using DataWeave 2.0?
Payload (CSV file) ANSI encoded:
"1";"John";"Smithß";30
"2";"Sächni";"Kumar";25
"3";"Kümar";"s";34

code:
<flow name="poc_oxaionFlow" doc:id="84217057-820f-4c6d-9d31-41495603da7e" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="6ab756e4-4d76-4d6e-ac85-91005b38caeb" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/file"/>
        <file:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="9ecd9d90-666e-4f97-9fb8-8a00d6be699a" config-ref="File_Config" path="file_poc_ANSI.CSV" outputMimeType="application/csv" outputEncoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="6d588ef9-60ca-414c-9178-919df0b2e50e" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inPayload = read(payload.^raw, "application/csv", {separator : ";", header:false})
---
inPayload map((item,index)->{
    "id":item[0],
    "firstName":item[1],
    "lastName":item[2],
    "age":item[3]
})]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="4f4c36ab-0674-4b0b-a6a0-e0c814ddf505" message="#[%dw 2.0&#10;output application/json&#10;---&#10;payload]"/>
    </flow>


I see now that you are using encoding ISO-8859-1, which is not exactly the same as Windows-1252 nor ANSI. What is the actual output and the expected output?

Expected output :-
[
{
"id": "1",
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Smithß",
"age": "30"
},
{
"id": "2",
"firstName": "Sächni",
"lastName": "Kumar",
"age": "25"
},
{
"id": "3",
"firstName": "Kümar",
"lastName": "s",
"age": "34"
}
].

And what is the actual output when you execute?

Works for me setting the CSV reader properties at the file connector. Note that the logger is not always the best way to visualize special characters because it may depend of the environment how they are displayed. I removed the extra output type at the logger, though it does not change the output is not needed.
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config"  >
    <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
</http:listener-config>
<file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config" />
<flow name="poc_oxaionFlow" >
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/file"/>
    <file:read doc:name="Read" config-ref="File_Config" 
        path="/tmp/file_poc_ANSI.CSV" 
        outputMimeType='application/csv; header=false; separator=";"' 
        outputEncoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" >
        <ee:message >
            <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map((item,index)->{
"id":item[0],
"firstName":item[1],
"lastName":item[2],
"age":item[3]
})]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
</flow>

Output:
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smithß",
    "age": "30"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "firstName": "Sächni",
    "lastName": "Kumar",
    "age": "25"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "firstName": "Kümar",
    "lastName": "s",
    "age": "34"
  }
]

